Is there a way to configure log warnings for incomplete patterns for case expressions in Hamlet templates?
Is there a way to set -Wincomplete-patterns for $case expressions in Hamlet templates?
Thanks.

Since Hamlet templates compile to real Haskell code, I would have expected that that was already the case. For example if a variable is missing in Hamlet, it errors, because converts it to a blaze-html "program" if you want.

It does throw only at runtime an "Internal Server Error" with "Non-exhaustive patterns in case". And no warning or error when {-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wincomplete-patterns -Werror=incomplete-patterns #-} at compile time.
